# Background Worker Using Service Reference from Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, service, reference, backgroundworker

I have a form on which I establish connection to a Windows Servie(Service Reference in my project). Then when user presses a button I have get latest data from the service. As the retrieval of the data takes a while I am thinking of using background worker so I don't block the UI. The question is: can I use the connection which has been established on load of the form? or will this crash my app/require invokes?

```
 class SomeWindowsForm
{

    public ServiceClient client
    onLoad()
    {
        client = new ServiceClient("Address"); //this is a Service Reference in my Project
        client.Connect();

        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(do_Work);
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(finished_Work);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler();
    }

    timer_tick()
    {
        client.SendPing(); // this keeps the connection
    }

    buttonClick()
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();// can I pass the client here to worker??? 
    }

    do_Work()
    {
        var log = client.getData(); // Is this allowed, I am callling the client which has been created in the form??
        return log;
    }

    finished_Work()
    {
        textBox.Text = e.Argument;    
    }
}
```

Comment: No invoke required nor crash unless you use simultaneously the connection on two threads simultaneously (and even in that case it may work). ServiceClient isn't a control so it will not throw a CrossThreadException.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the BackgroundWorker's result is assigned this way:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, 
    DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    e.Result =client.getData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not my question. I know the syntax.